# SVG Image don't show in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this svg image in my html in a theme of wordpress but it don't show me anything.

```
<img  src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/caribelogo.svg">
```

any ideas ?

Thank

Comment: Is this a child theme?

Comment: it not a child theme

Answer (score 0):

Try this, give a background color to your svg image. Some svg my be transparent.

`<img  src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/caribelogo.svg" style="background-color:orange;">`